# how to remove extra squared brackets in a response on djago rest framework

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, stored-functions

I created a stored function in PostgreSQL returns a table, and called that function in a Django-rest-framework like this:

```
def getSomeFunc(self):
   with connection.cursor() as cursor:
       cursor.execute(f'select json_agg(myfunctionpsql) from myfunctionpsql')
       table = cursor.fetchall()
   return table
```

this function is called in a views file, like a code below:

```
class myview(views.APIView):
   def get(self, request):
      fund = getSomeFunc(self)
      return Response({'data': fund}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

well the response is like this:

```
{
"data": [
    [ // I want to delete this
        [ // I want to delete this
            {
                "id": 21,
                "somedata": "FIX A",
                "somedata": "FIX A",
                "sometag": 0.95,
                "somdata": "005.119.745/0001-98",
                "somedatayear": 1.57,
                "somedata12": 4.11,
                "somedata36": 19.58,
                "somedata60": 51.9,
                "datarisk": 0
            }
        ]// I want delete this
    ]// I want to delete this
]
}
```

and I need response below:

```
{ "data": [{
            "id": 21,
            "somedata": "FIX A",
            "somedata": "FIX A",
            "sometag": 0.95,
            "somdata": "005.119.745/0001-98",
            "somedatayear": 1.57,
            "somedata12": 4.11,
            "somedata36": 19.58,
            "somedata60": 51.9,
            "datarisk": 0
        }]
 }
```

I try this:

```
class myview(views.APIView):
   def get(self, request):
      fund = getSomeFunc(self)
      reps = str(fund)[1:-1]
      return Response({'data': resp}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

but the response is all converted and return in a string, how to delete extra squared brackets, in a response.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `fund` is:

```py
[
    [
        [
            {
                "id": 21,
                "somedata": "FIX A",
                "somedata": "FIX A",
                "sometag": 0.95,
                "somdata": "005.119.745/0001-98",
                "somedatayear": 1.57,
                "somedata12": 4.11,
                "somedata36": 19.58,
                "somedata60": 51.9,
                "datarisk": 0
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

you can write a generator to flatten the items into a simple list, because I'm assuming that there could be multiple objects in your list and using indices to slice the list would be dangerous.

try this recursive generator:

```py
def flatten_list(data): 
     if isinstance(data, list): 
         for item in data: 
             yield from flatten_list(item) 
     else: 
         yield data
```

and call it like this:

```py
list(flatten_list(fund))
```

example:

```py
data = [[[1, 4], 2], 3]

list(flatten_list(data))

# result: [1, 4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: thanks Vedprakash, but not working well I try your code but not in "if" I don't know why not in, but the function fund = getSomeFunc(), is a list when I typed "type(fund) is list" the result is true, but in the "if" not in. do you know why not in statement if.